# Exim Verify Reciepient by existence of a file

Tags: exim

I want to configure **Exim** to verify and accept emails only for users where a File exists. The File itself lies in a Folder constructed by paths of the Filename. (*for use with modified mailman*):

the mail for "**mailing_address.tld@domain.tld**" should only be accepted if a file exists:

```
/var/lib/mailman/a/ad/domain.tld/mailing/config.pck
```

So

```
/var/lib/mailman/{first letter of address "**a**"}/{first and second letter of address "**ad**"}/{first part of local_part delimtered by _ "**mailing**"}/config.pck
```

I've tried with exim sg and substring but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with sg and substr:

> MM_NAME=${sg{$local_part}{_.*}{}}
>
> MM_DOMAIN=${sg{lc::$local_part}{.*_}{}}
>
> MM_LISTCHK=/var/lib/mailman/lists/${substr{0}{1}{MM_DOMAIN}}/${substr{0}{2}{MM_DOMAIN}}/MM_DOMAIN/MM_NAME/config.pck

it's 3 parts but works like intended